# replacing certain numeric values in a column using a condition and a loop

Tags: r

i'm trying to figure out how to correct a few entry errors in a dataset i'm working with. i already fixed the problem, but i think the way i did it was inefficient because i replaced the values individually using a condition instead of iterating through the column and replacing the values using a condition.

in my dataset there were three observations for the `corruption_score` column that were off by a factor of 10. i wanted to loop through this column and replace any observation for that variable that is greater than 10 with itself divided by 10. example printout of my dataset is below.

```
# A tibble: 6 x 9
  country  year value deaths_per_100k region corruption_score  rank electricity_acc…
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>           <dbl> <chr>             <dbl> <dbl>            <dbl>
1 Iceland  2005 0.159            13.1 WE/EU               97     1              100
2 Finland  2005 0.232            13.7 WE/EU               96     2              100
3 New Ze…  2005 0.228            13.8 AP                  96     2              100
4 Finland  2006 0.271            13.1 WE/EU               9.6     1              100
5 Iceland  2006 0.156            12.8 WE/EU               9.6     1              100
6 New Ze…  2006 0.217            13.5 AP                  9.6     1              100
```

to solve this i tried to use a few different versions of this loop, including one in which the replacement operation is `obs <- obs / 10`, but i couldn't get anything to save outside of the loop. any advice? thanks in advance.

```
for (obs in wdi_gdp_long$corruption_score){
  
  if(obs > 10 & !is.na(obs)){
       
    wdi_gdp_long$corruption_score[obs] <- obs / 10
    
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Do `idx <- x > 10 & !is.na(x); x[idx] <- x[idx] / 10`, where `x` is `wdi_gdp_long$corruption_score`

Comment: Alternative: `x / ifelse(!is.na(x) & x > 10, 10, 1)`

Comment: Or `x * c(1, 1/10)[idx + 1]`

Comment: (@markus I've always found the boolean indexing coercion to feel weird ... I use it, but I don't always feel *happy* with them ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corruption_score can be *mutated* using the tidyverse library like in the code snippet below:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

wdi_gdp_long %<>%
    mutate (corruption_score = if_else(corruption_score > 10, corruption_score/10, corruption_score))
```